# Restar dos columnas sql

Tags: sql, postgresql

Tengo una tabla en postgresql la estructura es la siguiente:

```
clientes
---------------------
nombre
apellido
pago
deuda
saldo pendiente
```

El punto es que quiero restar los campos <kbd>**`pago - deuda`**</kbd> y el resultado que aparezca en `saldo pendiente`.

¿Me ayudan? ya que no entiendo la documentación.

Comment: Que es lo que has intentado hasta ahora?

Comment: pues nada que es primera vez que lo hago, soy nuevo en esto.

Comment: Tenes que intantarlo primero mijo y poner lo que has intentado, sino no es valida tu pregunta

Answer (score 4):

puedes hacer esto

```
 select clientes,nombre,apellido,pago,deuda,pago-deuda as pendiente from clientes
```

despues del from es el nombre de esa tabla supongo que se llama clientes

Answer (score 0):

Puedes restar directamente los campos y agregar un alias

```
SELECT nombre, apellido, pago, deuda, (pago-deuda) AS saldo_pendiente FROM clientes
```